# Is there any way to listen load event in nuxt 3 ssr?

Tags: server-side-rendering, nuxtjs3

When I used Nuxt 3 without ssr, images used to fire load event. But after switching to ssr server they doesn't.

Can I watch image loading status another way? I need to know if images loaded to hide preloader and show content for user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of `AppImg` component:

```
<template>
  <client-only>
    <img
      v-bind="$attrs"
      @error="setFallback"
      @load="onLoad"
    />

    <template #fallback>
      <img key="ssr" v-bind="$attrs" />
    </template>
  </client-only>
</template>
```

Wrap your image inside `<client-only>` component.

You might think that images will be missing on SSR, that's why you also need a `#fallback` slot to render an alternative image tag from server side.

Because they are the same element (img) on client side and server side, you also need to add a key `key="ssr"` to one of those elements. Be careful in case you have a `v-for` on this component.

And it work!